# How can I run the Wubi installer in a different language?

Tags: installation, windows, wubi, language-support

My copy of Windows is in a language that I don't know. I want to install Ubuntu via the (Windows-based) Wubi installer. How can I change the language so that I can read it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open up a command prompt window. (Press <kbd>Windows Key</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, then type `cmd`.)
2. Run `wubi.exe` with the `--language` option. Use the appropriate two-letter language code. Here's an example:

   ```
   f:\wubi.exe --language=en
   ```